# a python console application executed from within vscode integrated terminal not allowing arrow keys to select list items

Tags: python, list, visual-studio-code, arrow-keys

I have a file samlapi.py. Running the file pops up a dialog with a list of menu items on the terminal to select from. I cannot traverse the menu items using keyboard arrow keys on a terminal running within vscode. Executing the file in powershell or cmd I am able to traverse the menu items.

Have tried to uninstall python and vscode and reinstalling. Nothing has worked. Have tried running vscode with high privileges that has not worked. Have installed cmder but still same issue.  I thought of key bindings within vscode but not sure if that is the issue because the arrow keys work fine when looking at previous commands ran on the terminal for example.  Please help.

Comment: can you please share the code in question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the code: https://github.com/goraxe/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/samlapi.py
This is the general file but every org would customize it to their own needs.